# Difference between lutris, winetricks, and playonlinux?

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux, winetricks

I understand they all use WINE, and I have a slight understanding of what WINE does. But I don't really understand the difference between the mentioned softwares, and why or when to use one over the other. Thanks

Comment: When it's gaming time I boot with Windows 10. Then I use Ubuntu 16.04 within Windows Subsystem for Linux to run BASH and a few GUI's like `gedit` and my own GUI Linux scripts. It's another option to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lutris and Playonlinux basically do the same thing. They give you install scripts for windows games and those scripts install a validated combination of wine version, modules and parameters so that the windows app run with this configuration.

Comment: This is pretty old, but what about Wine Tricks? When or why would you use that over Lutris or Playonlinux?